# Metric defined on a measure space by $d(A,B)=\mu (A\Delta B)$?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Yesterday I suddenly came up with this idea: let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. For $A,B\in \Sigma$, define
$$
d(A,B)=\mu(A\Delta B), A\Delta B=(A\cup B)\backslash (A\cap B).
$$
By careful consideration on a Venn diagram, one can show that $d$ satisfy the triangular inequality, and is hence a pseudo-metric. If we identify all sets that have distance $0$ from each other, we get a metric space $\overline \Sigma$.

Is there any application of this metric in mathematics? Can this theory be developed any further?

Comment: In many ways, you are just describing $L^1(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and restricting attention to the indicator functions.  In this fashion, the advancement of this theory is exactly the study of $L^1(X,\Sigma,\mu),$ and there is definitely real applications of this.

Comment: As Brian said, this is a restriction of the $L_1$ metric. To see, this identify a set $A$ with the indicator $1_A$, and note that $\mu(A) = ||1_A||_1$. Then $1_{ A \Delta B} = |1_A - 1_B|$, so $\mu( A \Delta B) = || 1_A - 1_B||_1$. Note that you need to restrict to sets of finite measure to get a metric. You can also use the other $L^p$ norms.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is an elaboration of what has been written already in the comments.

Under the extra assumption that $\mu(X)<\infty$, your metric space $(\overline\Sigma,d)$ admits an isometric embedding into the metric space $L^1(X,\Sigma,\mu)$. The embedding is given explicitly by sending an equivalence class $[A]\in\overline\Sigma$ to the equivalence class $[1_A]\in L^1(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ containing the indicator function $1_A$. (Recall that elements of the $L^p$ spaces are equivalence classes of measurable functions which agree up to $\mu$-null sets, and that $1_A$ denotes the function taking the value $1$ on the set $A$ and taking the value $0$ on its complement.) This embedding is well-defined (i.e., not multi-valued) since the functions $1_A$ and $1_B$ are equal on $(A\triangle B)^c$, thus if $d(A,B)=0$ then $\mu(A\triangle B)=0$ so $1_A$ and $1_B$ agree up to a $\mu$-null set. The embedding is an isometry since (as noted in the comments)
$$
\int_X |1_A-1_B|\ d\mu=\int_X 1_{A\triangle B}\ d\mu=\mu(A\triangle B)=d(A,B).
$$

(The identity $|1_A-1_B|=1_{A\triangle B}$ is the key to all of this. It also shows that the triangle inequality for $d(A,B)$ is actually a special case of the usual triangle inequality for functions, in the form $|1_A-1_C|\leq |1_A-1_B|+|1_B-1_C|$.)

The image of this embedding can be characterized as the set of equivalence classes in $L^1(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ which contain a function taking values in $\{0,1\}$. Thus, the study of the properties of your metric space amounts to the study of a (relatively simple to describe) subset of the (very well-studied and famous) metric space $L^1(X,\Sigma,\mu)$.

By the way, this phenomenon (embedding a space of sets into a space of functions) works in lots of different settings and is formalized by the notion of [subobject classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subobject_classifier), which is the role played by the set $\{0,1\}$ in the previous paragraph.