# Symmetric difference in Lebesgue measurable sets induces a separable metric space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ denote the set of equivalence classes of Lebesgue measurable subsets $A\subset[0, 1]$
under the equivalence relation:

A ∼ B  iff  $\mu(A\Delta B)= 0$.

If $[A], [B] ∈ X$, set $d([A], [B]) := \mu(A\Delta B)$.

Now, how can we prove that (X, d) is a separable metric space?

It is straightforward to show that $d([A], [B]) = \mu(A\Delta B)$ induces a metric space, but how can we show there exists a countable subset of $X$ which is dense in $X$?

Comment: Notice that $\mu(A\triangle B)=\int|\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_b|\,d\mu$. Now, set of integrable indicator functions ($\{\mathbb{1}_A:\mu(A)<\infty\}$ is contained in $L_1(\mu)$. The latter is separable (polynomials are dense in $L_1(\mu)$ by Stone-Weierstrass theorem) Every subspace of a topological separable space is separable.

Comment: the study of the properties of your metric space amounts to the study of a (relatively simple to describe) subset of the (very well-studied and famous) metric space 1(,Σ,). Here is a similar posting: [Metric defined on a measure space by $d(A,B)=\mu (A\Delta B)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497828/metric-defined-on-a-measure-space-by-da-b-mu-a-delta-b)

Answer (score 2):

This comes either from the regularity of the Lebesgue measure or from its definition. For any Lebesgue mesurable set $A$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a finite union of intervals $I_1$,..., $I_n$ such that
$$\mu(A \Delta (\bigcup I_j)) < \varepsilon.$$
We may approximate each of these intervals with intervals with rational endpoints. So the countable set you are looking for is the set of subsets of $[0,1]$ which are finite unions of intervals with rational endpoints.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @William I am not sure to understand your comment. I gave the the countable subset required, didn't I?

Comment: Is it similar to say Borel sigma-algebra is generated by the family of open intervals with rational endpoints?  How can I generalize this concept to Lebesgue measurable set instead of Borel sigma-algebra? In your answer, I understand each interval can be approximated by intervals with rational endpoints, but I don't understand how there is a finite union of intervals that satisfies the inequality. Or, what is the regularity here?

Comment: If $B$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, then there exists a Borel set $B'$ such that $\mu(B \Delta B') = 0$ from the very definition of a Lebesgue measurable set. So an approximation of $B'$ is an approximation of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

The distance function $d(A, B) = \mu(A \Delta B)$ can be written as $\mu(A \Delta B) = \int_{[0, 1]} |1_A - 1_B|$. So in fact, $X$ is nothing more than $\{1_A : A \subset [0, 1]\text{ is Lebesgue measurable}\} \subset L^1([0, 1])$. This immediately implies that $X$ is a metric space.

For the separability, use the fact that if $\mu$ is a finite measure and $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra generating a sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$, then $\{1_A : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ is dense in $\{1_{E} : E \in \mathcal{F}\}$ in the space $L^1(\mu)$. This can be proven with the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem by showing that $\{E \in \mathcal{F} : E \in \overline{\{1_A : A \in \mathcal{A}\}}\}$ is a $\lambda$-system containing $\mathcal{A}$. Here the finiteness of $\mu$ is critical.

Finding an algebra is easy; take $\mathcal{A}$ to be the set of subintervals of $[0, 1]$ with rational endpoints. More generally, we can take any countable set $S$ such that $\sigma(S) = \mathcal{F}$, and then let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra generated by $S$ (it is not immediately obvious, but $\mathcal{A}$ is indeed countable).